# Display Grid para o IE11

Tags: html, css

Estou fazendo uma grade com o 7 itens conforme o código abaixo:

Meu código

```css
nav div.grade {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: -ms-grid;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-grid-auto-columns: 100px;

}

nav div.iten_grade {
    width: 220px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    text-align: center;
    height: 40px;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -moz-justify-content: center;
    -ms-justify-content: center;
    -o-justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -moz-align-items: center;
    -ms-align-items: center;
    -o-align-items: center;

    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -ms-border-radius: 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px 45px 0px 45px;
    /*Compatibilidade */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-grid;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    color: #555555;
    -ms-float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="grade">
  <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
       <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
  <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
  <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
  <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
  <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
  <div class="iten_grade">
          <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
</div>
```

Em outras palavras, estou fazendo um menu no rodapé da página, gosto do cliente, dentro de uma `fieldset` basicamente conforme imagem: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até aí tudo bem, mas o problema é que me deparei com clientes que usam o IE11 que simplesmente não tem compatibilidade. Mesmo usando `-ms-` o navegador não aceita. Os demais navegadores aceitaram: Chrome, FireFoz, Edge (Safari e Opera ainda irei testar).

Há outra forma de compatibilidade? Há tags exclusivas de compatibilidade para o IE11?

Desculpa se o texto ficou confuso!

Comment: Obs: Opera usa a mesma engine do Chrome não precisa testar

Comment: Cara nem todas as classes do Grid funcionam no IE10 e 11, pois esses IEs usam a especificação antiga do Grid a propriedade `grid-template-areas` por exemplo não existia na especificação antiga, vc pode consultar mais aqui https://rachelandrew.co.uk/archives/2016/11/26/should-i-try-to-use-the-ie-implementation-of-css-grid-layout/ tirando isso acho que vc consegue esse layout com FlexBox não precisa de Grid dependendo do que pretende. Se quiser faço um modelo com Flex pra vc.

Comment: Obrigado galera, ainda não fiz os testes, pois estou deixando essa compatibilidade por último. Vou estudar, testar, e aviso a vocês sobre o resultado.

Comment: Boa noite, hoje fui atuar no 'display:grid' para o IE11 e para minha surpresa: *Quando visualizei as div's estavam lado a lado conforme imagem acima...* Porque será?! Não sei!!!     Avisei aos clientes sobre essa dificuldade com o IE11 e sugeri apresentar um alerta informando aos usuários utilizarem os navegadores exceto o IE11. hugocsl se não for incomodo aceitaria o modelo para eu estudar e nos próximos aplicá-los. E obrigado pela aula que deste. Sveen obrigado pela dica, nem instalei no PC o Opera. – Diego Primo agora   editar

Comment: Cara como vc demorou alguns dias para colocar esse Comentário que gostaria de ver uma versão em flex box acabou que eu não vi. Sei que muito provavelmente vc já deve ter solucionado o problema. Mas caso ainda queira uma versão em Flex me fala que eu posso bolar um exemplo, junto de demais explicações etc...